# How to take JSON data from website but the Response None

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping

I want to take data maps from their API, and their format output is `JSON`

I make code like this:

```
r = requests.get(url)
if r.ok:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    soup.status_code
    j = json.loads(str(soup))
```

but there is an error occurs:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b5e25d767a8a> in <module>
      4     soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
      5     soup.status_code
----> 6     j = json.loads(str(soup))

D:\Anaconda\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    349     if cls is None:
    350         cls = JSONDecoder

D:\Anaconda\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

D:\Anaconda\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

And I checked the Response isn't `200` but `None`

How I can fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Beautiful Soup is for parsing XML or HTML, not JSON.

Comment: use a web browser to confirm the existence of the JSON data

Comment: If `r` is `ok` and the API returns json then just get json from `data = r.json()`

Comment: Why are you using BeautifulSoup? _How I can fix this?_ Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: What's the `status_code`?

Comment: why dont you add the full code, including the url, and tell us what you are trying to, so that we canhelp you

Comment: Thanks, @PraysonW.Daniel its works now!

Answer (score 0):

`bs4` is used for parsing HTML and the like.

You should check first the response type and the contents by either using `r.contents` or `r.text`. If there's nothing then you probably made a typo.

If your file is truly a JSON file, (especially geojson) there's no reason to load it so just store it in a file or variable. If you're doing a visualization project with something like `folium`, there will be a parameter which accepts the entire thing.

For example my code from a project few weeks back:

```
folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=r,
    data = df_filtered,
    key_on = 'feature.properties.ADMIN',
    columns=['Country','Skill Count'],
    fill_color='YlOrRd', 
    fill_opacity=0.7, 
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Clash Royale "Skill" level',
    reset=True
).add_to(mapp)
```

Comment: Thank you guys, I have received an answer from PraysonW.Daniel.
Thanks for all your help, I appreciate it :)